# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with http post in angular2

Tags: angular, http-post

I am getting the following error with POST request:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:port/v1/route2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

GET request is working perfectly fine. What could be the possible reason for the failure of POST? Is there any mistake in the `testPost`?
Here is the part of angular service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SampleService {
    private _getUrl: string = 'http://<server-ip>/v1/route1';
    private _postUrl: string = 'http://127.0.0.1:<port>/v1/route2';
    constructor(private _http: Http) {}
    testGet() {
        return this._http.get(this._getUrl).map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
    testPost() {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        this._http.post(this._postUrl, JSON.stringify({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}), headers).subscribe(() => {}, err => console.error(err));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with how you are passing the headers to the request. The headers should be wrapped in a `RequestOptions` object. Additionally, you do not need to stringify the JSON object because you are setting the `Content-Type` to `JSON`.

```js
testPost() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    this._http.post(this._postUrl, {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, options)
              .subscribe(() => {}, err => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: Now the error got changed to `OPTIONS http://127.0.0.1:port/v1/route2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. By the way, I have confirmed that the `port` is listening.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no port = port. You need to define a real port. By default it is 80 and your application is maybe running using this port, thats why get is working. But your explicit definition of the port in the second call is the issue.

Connection Refused means there is not real application handling you request. If the header would be wrong i guess the application itself would throw an (application) error

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problems which can cause these kind of errors

- Remove the port number after the IP address if your system don't need it.
- If you are communicating with PHP or other technologies, you should change the permission in .htacces file for the angular project.